# A web server that return the content of given url

Tags: go, webserver

I wrote a simple web sever that gets the content of a given URL and writes it out using a `http.ResponseWriter`. But the problem is that it does not display any images and CSS on the page. The code is given bellow:

```
func factHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    res, err := http.Get("http://www.meaningfultype.com/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }   
    w.Write(robots)
}
```

What do I need to change so that the the whole page content as seen in the web browser is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

- You are only serving the root HTML page, you need to respond to requests to other resources too (you can see what resource is being requested with the URL variable of the *http.Request variable)
- When serving the resources, you need to write the Header's `Content-Type` to let the browser know what's the type of the resource (like `image/png`)

## Full Answer

What you are doing in your request handler is getting `http://www.meaningfultype.com/`, the HTML page, then the browser finds an image like `/images/header-logo.png` and makes the request to get it but your server in localhost doesn't know how to respond to `http://localhost/images/header-logo.png`.

Assuming your handler function is handling requests at the root of the server (`"/"`), you could get the requested URL `r.URL` and use it to get the required resource:

```golang
url := "http://www.meaningfultype.com/"
if r.URL.Host == "" {
    url += r.URL.String()
} else {
    url = r.URL.String()
}
res, err := http.Get(url)
```

The problem is that, even after doing this, all the resources are sent as `plain/text` because you are not setting the Header's `Content-Type`. That's why you need to specify the type of the resource before writing. In order to know what the type of the resource is, just get it from the `Content-Type` you just received in the Header of the response of `http.Get`:

```golang
contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
w.Write(robots)
```

The final result:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", factHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func factHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := "http://www.meaningfultype.com/"
    if r.URL.Host == "" {
        url += r.URL.String()
    } else {
        url = r.URL.String()
    }
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    w.Write(robots)
}
```

Comment: how to manage it if url given in the example is not fix.e.g. i want to give any url in browser like given bellow:
http://localhost:8080/fastor/ttp://www.meaningfultype.com/

Comment: You just need to set the `url` variable to the right value. The variable `r.URL` contains the URL that the user requested (in this case http://localhost:8080/fastor/http://www.meaningfultype.com/) so you just need to remove `http://localhost:8080/fastor/` and use the rest of the string as the value for `url` but keep in mind that double slashes will be replaced with one slash so the URL in the path will become `http:/www.meaningfultype.com` it might be better to not include the scheme in the path and add it to the string manually.

Comment: I use this link http://www.elbowsydney.com.au in the code given by you and web server opened it nicely . But when I click on the internal links, browser opens the internal link directly without interacting with my web server.I would be very thankful to you

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is presumably that the website you refer is using relative paths for the images and stylesheets, e.g. `"/css/main.css"`. The local website that you deliver to the browser with your Go service has another domain (for example `localhost`) and thus the relative path cannot be resolved by the browser (there is no `http://localhost/css/main.css`).

So what you need to do is either set a base URL in the document you deliver or, alternatively, rewrite every relative path to an absolute path (`/css/main.css` to `http://originalwebsite.com/css/main.css`).

For adding the base tag or rewriting the URLs in the document I suggest employing something like [goquery](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) which lets you manipulate the HTML structure similar to how jQuery does it.

Example of adding a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag:

```
import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    doc,err := goquery.NewDocument("http://www.meaningfultype.com/")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    m := doc.Find("head")

    m.Children().First().BeforeHtml(`<base url="http://localhost/">`)

    fmt.Println(doc.Html())
}
```